# Entity Framework In Memory on MS SQL Azure

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to use in memory in Entity Framework on an Azure MS SQL database?

Azure has in memory MS SQL databases: [In merory Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-in-memory/)

If it is possible, is there any disadvances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,You can use EF if you'll full fill the below mentioned criteria.

> Databases that are at a Premium service tier.
>
> Databases that were created after the In-Memory OLTP features became
>   active.
>
> A new database cannot support In-Memory OLTP if it is restored from a
>   database that was created before the In-Memory OLTP features became
>   active.

[**Transact-SQL Constructs Not Supported by In-Memory OLTP**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn246937.aspx)

> Memory-optimized tables, natively compiled stored procedures, and
>   user-defined functions do not support the full Transact-SQL surface
>   area that is supported by disk-based tables, interpreted Transact-SQL
>   stored procedures, and user-defined functions. When attempting to use
>   one of the unsupported features, the server returns an error.

[**New Features and Enhancements in SQL Server 2016**](http://www.netwoven.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016-in-memory-oltp/)

> Support for Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS): In-Memory OLTP now
>   supports MARS using queries and natively compiled stored procedures.
>   This enables requesting data from multiple queries without the need to
>   retrieve each result set before sending the next request. MARS will
>   need to be explicitly enabled in a connection since its disabled by
>   default. With support for MARS, Entity Framework will be easier to
>   implement with In-Memory OLTP.

[image]

**Is that durable ?**

> They are fully transactional, durable and can be accessed using T-SQL
>   statements just like the disk-based tables. One version of the table
>   is stored in the active memory and the standard version is stored on
>   the hard disk. Transactions, however, only access data directly from
>   the version in the memory and hence run faster.

Comment: It's only for Premium service tier?
I could test i on a demo database. Just back up the old data, and load it in to the new. The structure hasent change, so that could by done.

Comment: Yes,but you cannot use it on production.for that you have to have `Databases that are at a Premium service tier`.That is their requirement at this moment.

Comment: Ok. And the in-memory data is async saved on disk? Or secured for data loses in other ways?

Comment: Please see the update under the `Is that durable ?`.

Comment: Super reply.. Thanks!

Comment: Where do I find updated information, is this still only a Permium service?

Comment: I just checked and as of Nov 2017 still Premium only. Thx.